# For Azure API Management - Consumption SKU does it support integration with Azure DevOps through Service Principles

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, azure-api-management

I have attempted to connect a service principle through azure devops using powershell scripts to deploy apis and manage updates on Azure APIM (Consumption SKU) and I get authorization failures.  I have checked the service principle and the permissions associated with the resource group for the apim and everything appears to be correct. I am able to do this using the Developer SKU of the Azure APIM without issue but I am wondering if this is a limitation of the Consumption SKU

Comment: There should be no such limitation, could you share more details about your scenario and error you're getting, please.

Answer (score 0):

Use powershell to connect service principle is related to Azure AD authentication. But you can refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features), it shows us APIM in Consumption SKU doesn't support Azure AD integration.

[image]

Comment: Azure DevOps not Azure AD

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue was a malformed resource group name in the url posted.   Resolved that and the Azure DevOps integration worked as expected.